# How do you change the size of permissions boxes in Django Admin section of Authentication and Authorization?

Tags: django, django-admin

As we know Django has an in-built Admin. I am using it but I cannot seem to get access to its code (perhaps I'm being an idiot, likely,- new to django and inherited an existing project). Crucially, since we are porting a legacy database to this new one there are permissions etc that are assigned to users and groups. As show in the picture below the display boxes for the permissions is too small preventing the administrator from being able to adequately assess the permissions options. How do I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

Copy the admin templates in the following directory (recommended by the official documentation)

```
your_project
     |-- your_project/
     |-- myapp/
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- myapp/
                  |-- template_you_are_overriding.html  <- do not misspell this
```

After you're done with that.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # <- add this line
        },
    },
]
```

Find the template you want to override in this folder:

`lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin`

If you have virtualenv access that first and look for the lib folder, if you have it installed directly, then access it from there.

After that you'd modify the template, as I'm assuming it's an HTML element with `rows` as an argument, so just modify that.